# Ioninc 7 : Tabs and Navigation

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I'm fairly new to development and am using Ionic Framework 7 for my build, using vanilla javascript.
I have used the following code to incorporate the tabbed navigation in my app and is working perfectly fine, now I want a page navigation for elements within the tab, but I'm not able to achieve so by ion-router : maybe it's not the right tool or my implementation is incorrect.

```
<style>
  .example-content {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>

<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab tab="home">
    <ion-nav id="home-nav"></ion-nav>
    <div id="home-page">
      <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar>
          <ion-title>Listen now</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
      </ion-header>
      <ion-content>
        <div class="example-content">Listen now content</div>
          **<ion-router>
           <ion-route url="/" component="page-one"></ion-route>
           <ion-route url="/page-two" component="page-two"></ion-route>
         </ion-router>
       <ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>**
      </ion-content>
    </div>
  </ion-tab>
  <ion-tab tab="radio">
    <ion-nav id="radio-nav"></ion-nav>
    <div id="radio-page">
      <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar>
          <ion-title>Radio</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
      </ion-header>
      <ion-content>
        <div class="example-content">Radio content</div>
      </ion-content>
    </div>
  </ion-tab>
  <ion-tab tab="library">
    <ion-nav id="library-nav"></ion-nav>
    <div id="library-page">
      <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar>
          <ion-title>Library</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
      </ion-header>
      <ion-content>
        <div class="example-content">Library content</div>
      </ion-content>
    </div>
  </ion-tab>
  <ion-tab tab="search">
    <ion-nav id="search-nav"></ion-nav>
    <div id="search-page">
      <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar>
          <ion-title>Search</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
      </ion-header>
      <ion-content>
        <div class="example-content">Search content</div>
      </ion-content>
    </div>
  </ion-tab>
  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
    <ion-tab-button tab="home">
      <ion-icon name="play-circle"></ion-icon>
      Listen Now
    </ion-tab-button>
    <ion-tab-button tab="radio">
      <ion-icon name="radio"></ion-icon>
      Radio
    </ion-tab-button>
    <ion-tab-button tab="library">
      <ion-icon name="library"></ion-icon>
      Library
    </ion-tab-button>
    <ion-tab-button tab="search">
      <ion-icon name="search"></ion-icon>
      Search
    </ion-tab-button>
  </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>

<script>
  const homeNav = document.querySelector('#home-nav');
  const homePage = document.querySelector('#home-page');
  homeNav.root = homePage;

  const radioNav = document.querySelector('#radio-nav');
  const radioPage = document.querySelector('#radio-page');
  radioNav.root = radioPage;

  const libraryNav = document.querySelector('#library-nav');
  const libraryPage = document.querySelector('#library-page');
  libraryNav.root = libraryPage;

  const searchNav = document.querySelector('#search-nav');
  const searchPage = document.querySelector('#search-page');
  searchNav.root = searchPage;
</script>
<script>
  class PageOne extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      this.innerHTML = `
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>Page One</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content class="ion-padding">
      This is the content for page 1.
      <ion-router-link href="#/page-two">
        <ion-button>Go to Page 2</ion-button>
      </ion-router-link>
    </ion-content>`;
    }
  }

  class PageTwo extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      this.innerHTML = `
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-buttons slot="start">
          <ion-back-button default-href="/"></ion-back-button>
        </ion-buttons>
        <ion-title>Page Two</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content class="ion-padding">
      This is the content for page 2.
    </ion-content>`;
    }
  }

  customElements.define('page-one', PageOne);
  customElements.define('page-two', PageTwo);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The ionic docs provide a working basic implementation like yours. https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/router#basic-usage

Comment: Using this creates two layers - where the ion-router runs in 95% of the window and  ion-tabs are pushed in background and is visibile only in the top 5% of the screen. I probably need a more legit way of using the two codes together.
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/router#basic-usage & https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/tabs